# MySQL query with joins on a table where second table name comes from a column in the first table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I think my title says it all, but in essence, this is what I want to do:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.friendly_name, CONCAT_WS(" ",t3.name,t3.surname) AS user FROM activity
        LEFT JOIN t1.typedb AS t2 ON t1.typeid = t2.id
        LEFT JOIN users AS t3 on t1.loginid = t2.loginid
        ORDER BY time DESC, user ASC
```

But as you can imagine, this will give me an error.

I can do a normal select on the activity db and then do a loop in php and run queries to fetch the info. But there has to be a way to do this in one query in MYSQL.

Please help.

Comment: not possible in standard sql. You'd need to build your query client-side, or use a stored procedure to dynamically build your query string and then execute it. There's no way to get "data" from a query to be used as part of an sql statement as if it was in there to start with.

Answer (score 0):

So there is a table name in typedb? Then no, SQL doesn't support this. This is not how a relational database is supposed to work.

You can try something along the lines of

```
SELECT 
  t1.*, 
  coalesce(x1.friendly_name, x2.friendly_name, x3.friendly_name) as friendly_name,
  CONCAT_WS(" ",t3.name,t3.surname) AS user 
FROM activity t1
LEFT JOIN tableX AS x1 ON t1.typeid = x1.id and t1.typedb = 'TABLEX'
LEFT JOIN tableY AS x2 ON t1.typeid = x2.id and t1.typedb = 'TABLEY'
LEFT JOIN tableZ AS x3 ON t1.typeid = x3.id and t1.typedb = 'TABLEZ'
LEFT JOIN users AS t3 on t1.loginid = coalesce(x1.loginid,x2.loginid,x3.loginid)
ORDER BY time DESC, user ASC;
```

But this is not very efficient. It's just not what SQL is made for. So use a programming language and build dynamic SQL, or even better: change your database design.